# How can I add spacing margin within razor @if?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

and 
's are not allowed in @if syntax...

Q: How can I add spacing/margin within a razor @if {} block?

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{      
   @* I need to add certain bottom margin here *@
}
else
{
   @* I need to add certain bottom margin here *@    
}

 @*  More stuff down here ... *@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@{
    var margin = string.Empty;
    if (condition1)
    {
       margin = "10px";;
    }
    else if (condition2)
    {
       margin = "20px";
    } 
}

<div style="margin-bottom: @margin">
 my stuff
</div>
```

This is one of many ways to do it